# Is there a way to enable the pass-through of the Windows key via VNC when using an external keyboard?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-keyboard, vnc

Im currently trying to get on a Linux machine via VNC with my Nexus 10 running the newest CM Nightly (Android 6.0.1) and using an external keyboard. It works largely fine, but the Windows Key doesnt register any X Event on Linux (meaning it isnt "pressed" via VNC), or simply acts as a shortcut on android (for example Win+Enters acts like the home button). This happens with all VNC Viewers ive tried so far. Things like alt+tab also only execute Android commands and arent seen via VNC. Is there any way to disable these shortcuts and make Android pass the Windows key to the apps?